# How to remove margin on listbox itemscontainer in wpf?

Tags: wpf, listbox, padding, listboxitem

I can't fixed my issue  about listbox padding on itemscontainer

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="MyListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="MyListBox">
    <Setter Property="ListBoxItemsContainer" Value="{StaticResource MyListBoxItem}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 0 0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>

<ListBox Style="{StaticResource MyListBox}"/>
```

How to catch the 1 pixel in listbox items containers?

Help me please!

[image: 1 pixel red space!!]

Comment: could you show the entire xaml code of the listbox?

Comment: i can show source code for you at after a hour
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding is [hard coded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864654/4838058) in the control template. Looks like the [template on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx) is already updated (Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"), but the default one used in VS isn't. As always when making changes to control templates, it takes a lot of XAML redefining everything.

Altered to your specific case

Reference

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Resources

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Opacity="0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="xform" X="-25"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="OpenStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                    <VisualTransition To="Open" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Border Margin="4,4,-4,-4" Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5"/>
        <Border Margin="3,3,-3,-3" Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4"/>
        <Border Margin="2,2,-2,-2" Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3"/>
        <Border Margin="1,1,-1,-1" Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2"/>

        <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2"/>
        <Border CornerRadius="2">
            <TextBlock 
                  UseLayoutRounding="false" 
                  Foreground="White" Margin="8,4,8,4" MaxWidth="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="MyListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="Blue">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyListBoxItem}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 0 0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border CornerRadius="2" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" 
                                             PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ToolTip.Triggers>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Grid Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                            <Path Margin="-1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C"/>
                            <Path Margin="-1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note that the ControlTemplate for ValidationTooltip is needed as per MSDN

> The default ControlTemplate for ListBox and ListBoxItem references the
>   ControlTemplate for ValidationTooltip. The following XAML shows the
>   ControlTemplate for ValidationTooltip that you must specify when you
>   work with the ListBox or ListBoxItem control templates.