# ListView template without gaps between columns

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a simple application with ListView control which has edited template to disable any selections. Basically it acts like Grid but it can get items using ItemsSource property and has columns. I've used template for ListView control from MSDN and removed all selections etc. but still 
some margins are still there and I can't get how to remove them.

The xaml is as follows:

```
    <Window.Resources>   
<!--Control colors.-->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

        <!--Border colors-->
        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

        <!--Control-specific resources.-->
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>



        <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}"
       TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          Focusable="false">
                                    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                          Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding
                Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding
                Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding 
                Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding
                Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding
                Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding
                Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding
                SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </ScrollViewer>

                                <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                    CanContentScroll="True"
                                    CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                                    CanVerticallyScroll="False" />
                            </DockPanel>

                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper"
       TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter Property="Width"
          Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                           EndPoint="0,1">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                          Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                          Offset="1.0" />
                            </GradientStopCollection>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Background="Transparent">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="1"
                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                           StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"
                      Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White"
                      Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}"
       TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder"
                  BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"
                  Padding="0,0,0,0">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                   EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                  Offset="0.0" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                                  Offset="1.0" />
                                            </GradientStopCollection>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                                </Border.BorderBrush>

                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent"
                              Margin="0,0,0,1"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <!--<Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                 Margin="0,0,-9,0"
                 Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}" />-->
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role"
             Value="Floating">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity"
              Value="0.7" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                <Canvas Name="PART_FloatingHeaderCanvas">
                                    <Rectangle Fill="#60000000"
                         Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                         Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" />
                                </Canvas>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role"
             Value="Padding">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                <Border Name="HeaderBorder"
                    BorderThickness="0,1,0,1">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                    Offset="0.0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                                    Offset="1.0" />
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListView}"
       TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                        <Border Name="Border"
                BorderThickness="10">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource
                        {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                   Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                   Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderLightColor}" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Padding="0"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <!--<Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>-->
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0">
                            </GridViewRowPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Xs" Width="150" x:Name="col1">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0">
                                    <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding Width, ElementName=col1}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>-->
                                    <TextBlock Text="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ys" Width="150" x:Name="col2">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding Width, ElementName=col2}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Y}"/>-->
                                    <TextBlock Text="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Xs" Width="150" x:Name="col3">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding Width, ElementName=col3}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ys" Width="150" x:Name="col4">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding Width, ElementName=col4}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Delete">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Delete"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

The codebehind is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.ItemsSource = new List<dynamic> { 
            new {X=5,Y=5},
        new {X=5,Y=5},
        new {X=5,Y=5},
        new {X=5,Y=5},new {X=5,Y=5},
        new {X=5,Y=5},
        new {X=5,Y=5},
        new {X=5,Y=5}};
    }
}
```

So the collection is drop dead simple, moreover ListView only shows multiple X and multiple Y strings for each item.

This is how application window looks like with gaps between columns.

[image]

How to remove gaps?

Comment: First thing I would do is to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the visual tree at runtime, with the running application, and try to find out what exactly those gaps are (is it a `Margin`?, a `Padding`?, an undesired element placed there?)

Comment: I found that values (6,0,6,0) investigating visual tree. This is what causing gaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [source code](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/NetFXw7/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GridViewRowPresenter@cs/1/GridViewRowPresenter@cs) this is the default margin for `GridViewColumn`s.

```
private static readonly Thickness _defalutCellMargin = new Thickness(6, 0, 6, 0);
```

This value is uses in private `CreateCell(GridViewColumn column)` method of `GridViewRowPresenter` and can't be overridden. Only thing you can do is setting an inverse margin in cell template.

```
Margin="-6,0"
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1351605/620360) too.